# What are my options for developing a method to allow users to upload photos and video to my website from a mobile device

Tags: php, iphone, upload, mobile-phones, photo

I want to allow users of my website to upload photos and video from their mobile phone. I have a web-based upload page (built using Flash) that posts uploads to a PHP script running on an Apache web server in Amazon EC2 cloud. I would like to use the same server to receive files uploaded by mobile.

The 3 options as I see it are - (could do all)

1) Develop a mobile browser optimised upload page (eg xhtml) - there is a tutorial mentioned in another question about this on stackoverflow. This would require the user to login beforehand so I know who has uploaded the file and where to put it in database.

2) Develop an app that will be able to access file system of mobile device and upload files. This could be configured once with the username and password of a user so uploading is a little easier.

3) provide an email address for users to send files to from their phone

And I suppose there is the option of using a 3rd party service for this, are there any open source scripts around?

Are there any other considerations I need to be aware of? How does iPhone fit in to this - I know that Flash for iPhone is not supported (yet) but will be in the next version of Flash (for apps not browser based). The tutorial I mentioned above would not work with iPhone either as you cannot get access to file system on iphone via web page.

any other information is greatly appreciated. 
many thanks

Comment: it's amazing how out-of-date things become in computing.  of course you just use parse.com (or any similar baas) for this today.  it's one or two lines of code and is quite free.   it's astounding this used to be "a whole startup dotcom project" and its now a trivial line or two of code and a couple of free accounts.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1 is not possible on all phone OSes, especially the iPhone OS.

Option 2 is too expensive in time and resources, because you would have to make sure the app runs on all phone OSes and each and every device. Think different screen dimensions, touch screen or not, has a camera or not. Developing native apps is just too much hassle for just an upload feature.

Option 3 is supported by many - if not, all - smartphones. Email is incredibly easy to explain, just place a mailto link on your users personal page so he can click to launch his phone's standard email client. He can also save the email address as a contact and "share" media with this new "contact".

I think you should go for option 3.

Comment: Thanks Rick, what about supporting email on our EC2 instance, is it possible to have email sent to our apache webserver on EC2? what are the steps involved in setting this up?

Answer (score 1):

Expose your photo upload as a RESTful web service, then you can connect to it with any client imaginable.

If you want to connect using the iPhone you'll use NSURLRequest, NSURLConnection, and UIImageJPGRepresentation().